# How to send request to an interactive website in java?

Tags: javascript, java, http, web-crawler, interactive

I'm developing a java program that takes a url to an mp3 audio and then changes some ID3 tags of it. And then gives back a url to the new file. for some reason I can't do it on the local computer and I want to use [this](http://tagmp3.net/) site. Now I have to submit the form:

```
<div id="urlForm">
  <form onsubmit="return validate(this)" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input name="filepath" type="text" class="textfield" id="filepath">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Next" class="submitbtn">
  </form>
```

which will get me to a new page like:

"http://tagmp3.net/tags.php?files=1760689.mp3"

And there I want to submit another form which will get me to another page and then my file is ready in the address:

http://tagmp3.net/save.php?f=1760689.mp3

How can I submit these forms to get to the download link of the file?

Comment: What's the use case? What are you trying to achieve? Out of what you've written, this sounds more like a task for `Selenium WebDriver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with HTML pages (execute javascript, fill out forms, etc.) you need a browser emulator. you should use a tool like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).